# React/JSX - map property not found in object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx, react-redux-form

Im new to react framework. I'm facing an issue and need some help here.

An API call will result in an object which has several object rows. 
I wanted to use map on that object to render the div's.

```
export default class SearchResult extends Component {

   static propTypes = {
       courses:React.PropTypes.object, 
   }

  render() {

     ....
     this.props.courses.map( entity => renderEntity(entity));
     ...
  }
}
```

I'm having an error stating map is not a property. After searching in google i found object doesnt have map property. Only arrays have it.

Can some one help me 
1) How do i get map functionality / equivalent. All I want to do is render a set of html tags for every element in the object. this is to develop a search result.
2) Can I convert object to arrays. Is that required.
3) if (this.props.courses) is always turning out to be true because it has **proto** initialised. In that case how will I check if courses really has data. courses.length etc didnt work as it doesnt have any property of length nor it is an array.

[Object console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68bWH.png)
Note :- this is my first question in stackoverflow. So kindly ignore if you find any error.

Thanks in advance  for help.
Sesh

Comment: You can just say Object.keys( this.props.course).map and try to render this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than a `React` problem this is a pure JS one. If your need is to cycle through the values of the object, then something like this should work just fine:

```
Object.keys(this.props.courses).map(course => renderEntity(this.props.courses[course]))
```

As a suggestion for future issues like this, always start looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), in this specific case [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), is the ideal like for your problem.